# Python programming decimal rounding for CSE 231

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this is my code right now:

```
'= input("Input a float: ") 
in_input = float ( s ) 
'{:{width}.{prec}f}'.format( in_input, width=12, prec=2) 
'{0:10.2f}'.format ( in_input ) 
print (in_input)'
```

It works perfectly, but I need to get the output so that it goes two decimals after the integer and stops. For example, my current code's output is 1234.56789 and 3456.0, I need to get it to say 1234.57 and 3456.00 instead

Comment: It is not true that your code as shown "works perfectly"--you have spare single-quote marks in the code, there is no variable on the left hand side of the first statement, and so on. Please edit the shown code so it agrees with your working code.

Comment: You have to explain what your code do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**round**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

```
input_float = float(input("Input a float: ")) 
print("%.2f" % round(input_float, 2))
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Input a float: 1234.56789
1234.57
```

---

```
Input a float: 3456.0
3456.00
```

Comment: It worked, thank you!